# Is it possible to order items of a complex css grid system?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, grid-system

I am playing around with CSS grids.

I'd like to create a grid CSS structure where I can easily change the visual position of any item. How can I do it?

To explain better my problem I have created a css grid system with 4 columns and 23 rows, as you can see in the snippets. I give a order number to any item with `order` propriety.

Question: How can I change, for example, the item "Social Company" (`order: 8;`) with the item "Auto description" (`order: 10;`)?

I think it's possible only if we are speaking about items with the same size, right?

With `@media (max-width: 479px)` i can easily change the visual order of the items using `display: flex`.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(23, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 0;
}

.social {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 2;
}

.breadcumbs {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 3;
}

.next {
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 4;
}

.ads-1 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 5;
}

.foto-company {
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 6;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 130px;
}

.contact-company {
  grid-area: 5 / 2 / 6 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.direction-company {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  order: 1;
}

.address-company {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  order: 2;
}

.telephone-company {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  order: 3;
}

.budget-button {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
  order: 4;
}

.mini-ads {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 5 / 3;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 5;
}

.social-company {
  grid-area: 6 / 1 / 7 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 8;
}

.ads-2 {
  grid-area: 7 / 1 / 8 / 5;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 9;
}

.auto-description {
  grid-area: 8 / 1 / 9 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 10;
}

.stars {
  grid-area: 9 / 1 / 10 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 11;
}

.ads-3 {
  grid-area: 10 / 1 / 11 / 4;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 12;
}

.description-company {
  grid-area: 11 / 1 / 12 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 13;
}

.ads-4 {
  grid-area: 12 / 1 / 13 / 4;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 14;
}

.hours {
  grid-area: 13 / 1 / 14 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 15;
}

.ads-5 {
  grid-area: 14 / 1 / 15 / 4;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 16;
}

.map {
  grid-area: 15 / 1 / 16 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 17;
}

.if-budget {
  grid-area: 16 / 1 / 17 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 18;
}

.tags {
  grid-area: 17 / 1 / 18 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 19;
}

.ads-6 {
  grid-area: 9 / 4 / 18 / 5;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 20;
}

.ads-7 {
  grid-area: 18 / 1 / 19 / 5;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 21;
}

.more-companies-description {
  grid-area: 19 / 1 / 20 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 22;
}

.more-companies-1 {
  grid-area: 20 / 1 / 21 / 2;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 23;
}

.more-companies-2 {
  grid-area: 20 / 2 / 21 / 3;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 24;
}

.more-companies-3 {
  grid-area: 20 / 3 / 21 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 25;
}

.more-companies-4 {
  grid-area: 20 / 4 / 21 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 26;
}

.google-search {
  grid-area: 21 / 1 / 22 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 27;
}

.ads-8 {
  grid-area: 22 / 1 / 23 / 5;
  background-color: #FF6666;
  order: 28;
}

.footer-1 {
  grid-area: 23 / 1 / 24 / 4;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 29;
}

.footer-2 {
  grid-area: 23 / 4 / 24 / 5;
  background-color: #E0E3E3;
  order: 30;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  .mini-ads {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 5 / 3;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"> Logo</div>
  <div class="social"> Social </div>
  <div class="menu"> Menu </div>
  <div class="breadcumbs"> Breadcumbs </div>
  <div class="next"> Next </div>
  <div class="ads-1"> Ads 1 </div>
  <div class="foto-company"> Foto company </div>
  <div class="contact-company">
    <div class="direction-company">Company Name</div>
    <div class="address-company">Address</div>
    <div class="telephone-company">Telephone + Email + Web</div>
    <div class="budget-button">Budget button</div>
    <div class="mini-ads">Mini ads</div>
  </div>
  <div class="social-company"> Social company </div>
  <div class="ads-2"> Ads 2 </div>
  <div class="auto-description"> Auto description </div>
  <div class="stars"> Stars </div>
  <div class="ads-3"> Ads 3 </div>
  <div class="description-company"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnis illum aeterno pri id, usu habemus urbanitas ad. Pri veri aperiri delicata te. Cu ponderum partiendo adolescens eum, volutpat facilisis qualisque te eum. At cum sonet affert soleat. Duo utinam blandit no, cum oblique
    prompta probatus ea. Porro everti ponderum pri ea, at mei erat delenit. Est cu hinc case nostrud, te errem persecuti usu, quo eu reque option fabellas. Id mea errem salutandi urbanitas, impetus tractatos ex qui, ubique possit laoreet te eum. Nobis
    omnes tempor has ex. Ad qui disputando adversarium, pri altera dissentiunt ea. Vero utamur nam te, cu vel nobis necessitatibus.</div>
  <div class="ads-4"> Ads 4 </div>
  <div class="hours"> Hours </div>
  <div class="ads-5"> Ads 5 </div>
  <div class="map"> Map </div>
  <div class="if-budget"> If Budget </div>
  <div class="tags"> Tags </div>
  <div class="ads-6"> Ads 6 </div>
  <div class="ads-7"> Ads 7 </div>
  <div class="more-companies-description"> More companies description </div>
  <div class="more-companies-1"> More companies 1 </div>
  <div class="more-companies-2"> More companies 2 </div>
  <div class="more-companies-3"> More companies 3 </div>
  <div class="more-companies-4"> More companies 4 </div>
  <div class="google-search"> Google search </div>
  <div class="ads-8"> Ads 8 </div>
  <div class="footer-1"> Footer 1 </div>
  <div class="footer-2"> Footer 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You question is not entirely clear. The `order` property works the same in grid and flex CSS.

Comment: @Michael_B The OP problem is that these items have a grid-area set. And in this case order is irrelevant. Anyway, it still isn't clear why would someone set at the same time an area and an order

Comment: Thanx Michael. It's not clear because i'm not a professional, sorry :)
So, if I want give a order i can' t have a grid-area set. Simply I create the items and i order them, right?

Comment: For example,  I create all the items like this: 
grid-area: span 1 / span 3; 
Right?